# access array of object data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting an array of object from my rest API and try to access in flutter but I can not access.I want to access **posts,comments,like** and **status**.

The error code is **The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data
and error is given by line **snapshot.data!.data[index].posts[postPosition].url** and **snapshot.data!.data[index].status**
The data from API:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e902",
        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
        "posts": [
            {
                "postType": "image",
                "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e903"
            },
            {
                "postType": "image",
                "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e904"
            }
        ],
        "status": "testing status",
        "comments": [
            {
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "Testing comment",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e907",
                                "isNotified": true
                            },
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "_id": "6305f8d07d513ce62b9c099f"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e906"
                    },
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "_id": "6305f8d07d513ce62b9c099f"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "_id": "6305f8f67d513ce62b9c09a2"
                    }
                ],
                "commentId": "bc174de0-22f1-11ed-9c5d-23d89a83ff32",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e905"
            },
            {
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T15:02:11.123Z",
                "commentId": "90928740-22f4-11ed-b912-e99836187b6d",
                "_id": "6304ec67825b5926f0f074cf",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "_id": "6305f8d07d513ce62b9c099f"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "_id": "6305f8f67d513ce62b9c09a2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T15:02:11.123Z",
                "commentId": "90928740-22f4-11ed-b912-e99836187b6d",
                "_id": "6304ec81825b5926f0f074d1",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "_id": "6305f8d07d513ce62b9c099f"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "_id": "6305f8f67d513ce62b9c09a2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "likes": [
            {
                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                "_id": "63052dc7a1728d463769681b"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63070a03584ed0febe5b5a5f",
        "status": "testing",
        "posts": [],
        "comments": [],
        "likes": []
    }
]
```

Flutter code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 600,
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Posts>>(
        future: fetchPost(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true, 
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.data[index].posts!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, postPosition) {
                       return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data!.data[index].status),
                        ListView.builder(itemCount:snapshot.data!.data[index].posts.length,itemBuilder: (context, postPosition) {
                          return Column(children: [
                            Image.network(snapshot.data!.data[index].posts[postPosition].url)
                          ],);
                      })
                      ],

                       );
                      }
                }
                );
          } else
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
      ),
    );
}
```

The Posts class:

```
List<Posts> postsFromJson(String str) => List<Posts>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Posts.fromJson(x)));

String postsToJson(List<Posts> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Posts {
    Posts({
         this.id,
         this.userId,
        required this.posts,
         this.status,
        this.comments,
         this.likes,
    });

    String? id;
    String? userId;
    List<Post> posts;
    String? status;
    List<Comment>? comments;
    List<Like>? likes;
    factory Posts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Posts(
        id: json["_id"],
        userId: json["userId"],
        posts:  List<Post>.from(json["posts"].map((x) => Post.fromJson(x))),
        status: json["status"],
        comments: List<Comment>.from(json["comments"].map((x) => Comment.fromJson(x))),
        likes: List<Like>.from(json["likes"].map((x) => Like.fromJson(x))),
    );

  get length => null;

  get data => null;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "userId": userId,
        "posts": List<dynamic>.from(posts.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "status": status,
        "comments": List<dynamic>.from(comments!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "likes": List<dynamic>.from(likes!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}
```

Comment: How does `Posts` class looks like

Comment: i will post class

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your IDE lets you compile the code while you added type in `FutureBuilder`.
The problem seems here. After `snapshot.data` you should not add another `data` variable. `snapshot.data!.data` should not be added.

```dart
                      itemCount: snapshot.data![index].posts!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, postPosition) {
                       return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data![index].status),
                        ListView.builder(itemCount:snapshot.data![index].posts.length,itemBuilder: (context, postPosition) {
                          return Column(children: [
                            Image.network(snapshot.data![index].posts[postPosition].url)
                          ],);
```

Comment: can you provide full code?,it is not working

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Why are you adding nested `ListView`? Its not a good approach.

Comment: code is not compiling ,the error message is given by IDE

Answer (score 0):

from your api response and you named it as "class:Post" it not a list. but Post.post is a list. Try to delete the list just like this, and print the result. you may have other error when casting it to your widget because the code will be a bit different. you can ask more if you face other difficulties

example:

```
PostModel postModelFromJson(String str) =>
    postModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String postModelToJson(PostModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());
```